# No matching function for call to (list and push_front)

Tags: c++

For the game mastermind I need to generate all possible guesses.
I want to place them in `list<char[]>`.
I still get this error about `push_front`.

Can somebody help me?

```
void Mastermind::genereercodes (int getal, list<char[]> mogelijkeGok)
{
char gok[aantGaatjes+1]; //aantGaatjes is an integer
for (int i = 0; i < aantGaatjes; i++){
    gok[i] = (getal % aantKleuren) + '0'; //aantKleuren is an integer
    getal = getal / aantKleuren;
} // for
mogelijkeGok.push_front (&gok);

}   // genereercodes
```

This is the error I get:

```
mastermind.cc: In member function ‘void Mastermind::genereercodes(int,std::__cxx11::list<char []>)’: 
mastermind.cc:200:32: error: no matching  unction for call to ‘std::__cxx11::list<char []>::push_front(char *)[(((Mastermind*)this)->Mastermind::aantGaatjes + 1)])’
mogelijkeGok.push_front (&gok);
```

Comment: `char gok[aantGaatjes+1];` That's not valid C++ unless aantGaatjes is a compile time constant. If it works anyway, you are relying on compiler extensions (VLA), making your code non-portable.

Comment: All the problems you're having stem from using C-style arrays instead of std containers. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The problem is trying to convert a `char[N]` to a `char []`. Just use `std::list<char *>` instead of `std::list<char []>` and do `mogelijkeGok.push_front(gok);` (that is, allow the array to decay to a pointer).

Comment: `mogelijkeGok.push_front (&gok);` – bound to fail in any case, `gok` is a local variable that get's destroyed on leaving the function (so even if you manage to successfully `push_front`, you'll remain with a dangling pointer!). `&gok` is of type `char(*)[...]`, *not* `char*`!

Comment: @Cornstalks this is actively harmful advice. See the comment below as to why that is.

Comment: I have used #include <iostream>, #include <list> and using namespace std.

Comment: @nvr is `aantGaatjes` a compile-time constant? Do you know the value of it before the program runs?

Comment: The user needs to give up the value of aantGaatjes, so you dont know the value before the program runs.

Answer (score 1):

You're using C-style arrays for no reason. There are two possible replacements: `std::array` and `std::vector`. Since we know that:

> The user needs to give up the value of aantGaatjes, so you dont know the value before the program runs.

This leaves only `std::vector` on the table. One more thing that needs fixing is using the out-parameters, which, aside of being done incorrectly in your code, is bad practice regardless. The code then becomes:

```
std::vector<char> Mastermind::genereercodes (int getal)
{
    std::vector<char> gok(aantGaatjes+1);

    for (char& e : gok) {
        e = (getal % aantKleuren) + '0';
        getal = getal / aantKleuren;
    }

    return gok;
}
```

This doesn't handle appending to the list, and shouldn't need to. The caller having that list can simply call it like so:

```
mogelijkeGok.push_front(genereercodes(getal));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code; dropping irrelevant lines:

```
void Mastermind::genereercodes (int getal, list<char[]> mogelijkeGok)
{
    char gok[aantGaatjes+1];         // (1)
    mogelijkeGok.push_front (&gok);  // (2), (3)
}
```

1. Unless `aantGaatjes` is a compile time constant, you are creating a so-called 'variable length array'. This was introduced in C99 (bad mistake in my and others' eyes), but is not valid C++. Some compilers support it as an extension, though (e. g. GCC). 
   Relying on compiler extensions makes your code non-portable, another compiler might not provide the same support for, so prefer not to use extensions unless you have no other choice.
2. First issue with this line is the type of pointer you produce with `&gok`: It will be of type pointer to array of specific length (`char(*)[SomeLength]`), not pointer to char. If you need the latter, then just pass the array itself as argument, it will decay to pointer automatically (but I won't show explicitly due to (3)!).
3. `gok` is a local variable and as such will be destroyed immediately when exiting the function. What remains in your list then is a pointer to some object that has been invalidated long ago, i. e. a dangling pointer, using it will result in undefined behaviour!

To get around the third issue, you'd need to create an array with dynamic storage duration, i. e. `char* gok = new char[...];`. This would solve at the same time the first issue. ***But*** you then need to care for appropriate destruction at some later point, otherwise you will remain with a memory leak. However, there are two data types that allow for doing so automatically: `std::vector` and `std::array`. (Actually, there are even more, but these two are the most commonly used ones).

If all your arrays you produce have the same length, you might use `std::array`, otherwise need to use `std::vector`. You'd change your data structure as well, so your function might look like:

```
void Mastermind::genereercodes (int getal, std::list<std::vector<char>> mogelijkeGok)
{
    std::vector<char> gok;
    gok.reserve(aantGaatjes+1); // not absolutely necessary, but prevents re-allocations
                                // so always good idea to use if you know size in advance

    for (int i = 0; i < aantGaatjes; i++)
    {
        gok.push_back(getal % aantKleuren + '0');
        getal /= aantKleuren;
        //    ^  effectively does the same, but less to write and better to read...
    }
    mogelijkeGok.push_front(std::move(gok)); // move semantics, prevents unnecessary copy
}
```

A bit more optimised, avoiding moving, too:

```
mogelijkeGok.emplace_front();
std::vector<char&> gok = mogelijkeGok.front();
gok.reserve(aantGaatjes+1);
// rest as was, but no push_front, of course...
```

If you opt for `std::array`, you *should* use the optimised variant, as `std::array` cannot move its internal array, at best its array elements (not in given case, though), thus you'd always copy the arrays on pushing to front.

Answer (score -8):

You want to put in a list of char arrays a reference to a char array:

```
void Mastermind::genereercodes (int getal, list<char[]> mogelijkeGok)
{
char gok[aantGaatjes+1]; //aantGaatjes is an integer
...
mogelijkeGok.push_front (&gok);

}
```

should be:

```
void Mastermind::genereercodes (int getal, list<char[]> mogelijkeGok)
{
char gok[aantGaatjes+1]; //aantGaatjes is an integer
...
mogelijkeGok.push_front (gok);

}
```

Comment: This won't compile anyway. The bound of the array are not defined.

Comment: even if it did what you claimed, stdlib containers cannot store references.

Comment: This is very bad advice.  You're pushing a pointer to a function local object into the list.  When the function ends, the array is destroyed and you have dangling pointer.